# Woocommerce add custom select for customer on cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

how can I add custom select for customer on CART page? I need add option for my customers to select box for items and I have 5 types of boxes.

I can write code on my own, don't need expensive plugins, but I have no idea how to add it there and then show in BE order what my customer selected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you tried the [woothemes-tutorial](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) for this?

Comment: This is probably solution for my problem! Thank you

Comment: I've also written a [tutorial](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) about this. Leaving a link to [checkout field edifor](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-checkout-field-editor/) for reference.